# Calculate percentage between 2 columns in 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how to make a division between 2 columns in two separate tables.

I have 2 tables:

- **Races**, showing all races for all drivers

  ```
  Driver   | Race
  -----------------
  Driver 1 | Race 1
  Driver 1 | Race 2
  Driver 1 | Race 3
  Driver 2 | Race 1
  ```
- **Pposition**, showing the pole positions of all drivers

  ```
  Driver   | PP
  --------------
  Driver 1 | PP1
  Driver 1 | PP2
  Driver 2 | PP1
  ```

So, I would like to know how to get the percentage of pole positions of a driver (pole positions/total of races of the driver*100)

I have this query but it does not work, the result is an empty table

```
SELECT R.Driver,
    P.Driver,
    (P.Driver/R.Driver)*100 AS M2 
FROM Races AS R 
INNER JOIN Pposition AS P ON R.Driver=P.Driver 
GROUP BY P.Driver HAVING R.Driver > 10 
ORDER BY M2 DESC
LIMIT 0,50
```

The output that I want is something like

```
    Driver   | %
    -----------------
    Driver 2 | 100
    Driver 1 | 66.6
```

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: Can you add some sample output that you are expecting.

Comment: Please add a sample output and error if you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using subqueries.  For example:

```
SELECT R.Driver, S.Cnt AS Races, P.Cnt AS Poles, (P.Cnt / S.Cnt) * 100 AS M2
FROM Races AS R
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Driver, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Races) AS S ON S.Driver = R.Driver
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Driver, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM PPosition) AS P ON P.Driver = R.Driver
WHERE R.Driver > 10
ORDER BY M2 DESC
```

**EDIT:**

Here it is with a single subquery:

```
SELECT R.Driver, (P.Cnt * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS M2
FROM Races AS R
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Driver, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM PPosition GROUP BY Driver) AS P ON P.Driver = R.Driver
GROUP BY R.Driver, P.Cnt
ORDER BY M2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

But, the answer by dub stylee have a error which must be fix -

```
Column 'PPosition.Driver' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

This is how I would do it -

First, divide your problem into parts. Get grouped data from each table -

```
SELECT Driver, Count(Race) as [Races]
FROM Races
GROUP BY Driver

SELECT Driver, COUNT(PP) as [pposition]
FROM Pposition
GROUP BY Driver
```

Then, we are plug it into a query that join a multiple queries -

```
SELECT R.Driver, (P.pposition/R.Races)*100 AS M2 
FROM 
(
-- Put 1st query here
) AS R
INNER JOIN -- or left join
(
-- Put 2nd query here
) AS P
ON R.Driver = P.Driver
```

Then, final query is become -

```
SELECT R.Driver, (P.pposition/R.Races)*100.00 AS M2 
FROM 
(
SELECT Driver, Count(Race) as [Races]
FROM Races
GROUP BY Driver
) AS R
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT Driver, COUNT(PP) as [pposition]
FROM Pposition
GROUP BY Driver
) AS P
ON R.Driver = P.Driver
```

Using only the data which you have give in the question, I get a output -

```
Driver  M2
Driver 1    100.00
Driver 2    100.00
Driver 3    NULL
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I was missing a GROUP BY in my edit.  I have fixed my answer to reflect the changes.  Thanks for pointing it out Borat.